# How to call CupertinoPicker

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to show CupertinoPicker, when some button is pressed.
However I have no idea where I should implement CupertinoPicker.

Following code is sample of code which I don't know where I write to call.

```
showCupertinoModalPopup<String>(
  context: context,
  builder:(BuildContext context){
    return _buildBottomPicker(CupertinoPicker(
      onSelectedItemChanged: (value){
        setState((){
          selectedValue = value;
        });
      },
      itemExtent: 32.0,
      children: const[
        Text('Item01'),
        Text('Item02'),
        Text('Item03'),
      ],
    ));
  },
);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is the complete workable demo for launching cupertino picker when a button is pressed. Hope this solves your query.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: WeightSelect(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class WeightSelect extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WeightSelectState createState() => _WeightSelectState();
}

class _WeightSelectState extends State<WeightSelect> {
  int selectedValue;

  showPicker() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return CupertinoPicker(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            onSelectedItemChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                selectedValue = value;
              });
            },
            itemExtent: 32.0,
            children: const [
              Text('Item01'),
              Text('Item02'),
              Text('Item03'),
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Cupertino picker demo"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
          Text("Selected: $selectedValue"),
          const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
          Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: showPicker,
              child: Text("Show picker"),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It should be written when you want to open a popup or alertdialog with iOS cupertino style.

You can view the demo here :
http://flutterdevs.com/blog/know-your-widgets-1-cupertino-ios-style-actionsheet-in-flutter/

It may be displayed on button click when you need some confirmation or direction from the user.
[image: As per given below]

Comment: I'm supposed to call when button pressed. `RaisedButton(
            onPressed: cupertinoModalPopup,
            child: Text('Open Dialog'),
          ),`